# iPhone: Zombie object in modalview and delegate

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a crash in my App that sometimes occurs, I tested with zombies enabled and this method it found as a ZOMBIE, this method usually works OK but in some conditions like lots of navigate back and forth at somepoint it crashes.

**I retain the datepickerView in @property and release it in deaaloc.**

[image]

Comment: Is datePickerView set to retain?

Comment: Is datePickerView "assign" or "retain" property (sniped)?

Comment: Might be wise to indicate that you're using a 3rd-party extension as it was not immediately evident at the beginning.

http://reednj.tumblr.com/post/1346445326/ios-semi-modal-date-picker-for-iphone

Comment: Do you think, you really need to create an properties for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the datePickerDelegate to nil in dealloc.  If it has a retain property after the first instantiation the delegate will probably have a dead reference in it and will randomly cause creates and crashes when Zombies are enabled.  The crash happens because retain properties release the previous value and if it is a dead reference crashes ensue -- randomly. Also **best to set delegates to assign, not retain**.

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on on (you have to stop recording to set the option).  Cause the picker to run, stop recording, search for there ivar (datePickerView), drill down and you will be able to see  where all retains, releases and autoreleases occurred.

[image: Reference Counts]

Comment: tnx, setting delegete to assign solved my problem, very smart

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to keep the picker in memory after it has been popped from stack...

Instead of retaining the DatePickerController, remove "autorelease", and "release" just after presentSemiModalViewController, as per reednj post on SemiModelDatePicker

```
TDDatePickerController* datePickerView = [[TDDatePickerController alloc] 
                              initWithNibName:@"TDDatePickerController" 
                              bundle:nil];
datePickerView.delegate = self;
[self presentSemiModalViewController:datePickerView];
[datePickerView release];
```

Hopefully this will alleviate the problem. Otherwise, it could simply be a problem with the SemiModalDatePicker extension.